# How do I move the sending and receiving of messages to a server thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming

I have a class Game that uses a class `TCPServer`. I would like to seperate all the low level sending and receiving in `TCPServer`. So I give `TCPServer` a separate thread that constantly reads incoming messages. I would like to return these messages to `Game`. But I dont know how to do this. `Game` should also react on these messages bij responding by sending a message to the clients.

I think/know it is possible by moving the thread from `TCPServer` to `Game` but is this the best way to solve this? Isn't it better to keep the 2 classes separate.

I have the following pseudocode.

```
public class Game{
   TCPServer tcpServer = new TCPServer();

   public void execute(){
       // do something
       Object o = new Object;
       send(o);

       if(receive(o)){  // WRONG
          // do something with the receive object
       }
   }

   private void send(Object o){
      tcpServer.send(o);
   }

   private Object receive(Object o){
      return tcpServer.receive(o);
}

public class TCPServer extends Thread{
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;
   Socket client = new Socket;

   public void run(){
     Object o = receive();
     // How do I get this object o in the Server class in function execute()?
   }

   private Object receive(){
      return serverSocket.listen();

   }

   public void send(Object o){
      client.send(o);
}
```

Comment: Answering title of your question -- you will need data container shared between game logic and network logic. Basically, some subtype of `Queue`. But since there are lot of shortcomings in your current code, I'd suggest to start from reading Java tutorial about network programming -- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: And, yes, you are right: it's a very good idea to separate game logic from network-related stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the right way to do this would be by using `BlockingQueue`s.  Instead of sending the messages in the current thread, `Game` would just add them to a `sendQueue`.  The `TCPServer` would then have a receiving thread which would add things to the `readQueue` and another thread which wrote things from the `sendQueue` to the socket.

I don't quite understand your thread model right now.  Typically you have a thread calling `accept()` on a `ServerSocket` and then forking a client handler thread.  If `Game` is maintaining a number of these client connections then you'd have something like this:

1. TCPServer has a thread which calls `accept()`.
2. When it gets a connection is creates a `ClientHandler` object and adds this to the collection of clients being handled by the game.
3. Each `ClientHandler` has a `sendQueue` and `receivedQueue` -- maybe each are `LinkedBlockingQueue`
4. Each `ClientHandler` forks a reading thread receiving from the client and adding to the  `receivedQueue` and a writing thread which is waiting on the `sendQueue` and writes to the client socket.

There's a lot of work here to get this right.  How to properly shutdown both reader and writer threads when the client socket closes is going to be a challenge.

Hope something here helps.

Comment: Ok ty for your respons. Two questions. Do you keep the array of ClientHandler object in Game or in TCPServer? Second question after receiving a message from the client, the message is held in receivedQueue in the clientHandler. How would I access those message in Game without polling all the clientHandlers for new messages?

Comment: Good questions @fibera.  I assume the `Game` needs to interact with all of the clients.  It needs access to the collection of client (which needs to be synchronized somehow of course) but it could be in the TCPServer or Game.  If TCPServer created the client then it should manage the list I guess.

Comment: In terms of having to poll the multiple handlers @fibera, there could be a central read queue instead of a read queue per client.  But you would need a wrapper object that which has the ClientHandler and the read object in it.  That wrapper would be added to the central read queue.

Comment: So you have a single read queue. This queue is held with all the clientHandlers in a wrapper object.But then what do you mean by "that wrapper would be added to the central read queue"?

Comment: Sorry @fibera, I mean when each of the client receives a message, it will add the message to a wrapper object with its own handler object and add that to the central read queue.  So the `Game` will read from one queue, process the incoming message, and write back to the associated handler that it gets from the wrapper object.

Comment: Ok now I see, thanks for clearing that up. But in this case, Game has to poll also. But this time only from the central read queue. Is this correct? Or is there a way, that lets Game know when there are object in the central queue?

Comment: @fibera Game can be waiting on a wrapper work object to be added to the queue.  If it needs to do other stuff then it will have to poll -- either the queue or some other notification.